# Turbo core not working

Tags: amd-processor, cpufreq, turbo-boost

I got ubuntu 14.04 on hp pavalion g6 with an amd apu a6 llano which has a stock frequency of 1500mhz and is capable of boosting to 2400mhz.
But on my system it's turbo boost feature is not working.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://askubuntu.com/a/501599/308343 -- and it's safe to forget about the tips of CG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that turbo core is working to `cpufreq` just doesn't show that to see that it's working use these command

```
sudo modprobe -v msr
sudo cpufreq-aperf
```

it's shows average cpu frequencies over period of time and don't forget using performance cpu governor.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on my dell inpiron, and solved it though several steps.  There are a few needed applications, and an edit to /etc/rc.local

Install indicator-cpufreq, cpufrequtils:  Open a terminal window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
sudo apt-get install cpufreq-utils
```

These will help monitor your cpu

The edit to rc.local tells Ubuntu to ignore some settings in your bios, and will need to be customized for the number of CPU's that you have.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Before the line which says "exit 0", enter the lines

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc

for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-3]/cpufreq/;do 
  echo 2501000 > $x/scaling_max_freq
done
```

replace "2501000" with the maximum frequency of your CPU, in kHz (it should be 2401000) - the extra '1' in the frequency indicates turbo mode

You can determine the max frequency your system supports by

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

Reboot, and everything should be good.

Comment: it's not working dude I tried it but no result.

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` and `cat /etc/rc.local`

Comment: ok dude i don't have enough privilege to post image so I am posting a link to image https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4af80i46bli8b7/Screenshot%20from%202014-07-23%2020%3A34%3A42.png

Comment: K - it looks like Ubuntu is detecting max frequency as 1.5 Ghz.  We've reached the limit of my ability to do anything - my system always listed higher available frequencies, but would not access them before.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, Charles, but you sound like you're not familiar with the details of @Jarvish 's case.

Comment: @Jarvish  There is a thread you might follow at http://askubuntu.com/questions/43764/how-do-i-get-turbo-boost-working

Comment: @ClassStacker  You are correct that I am not familiar with the details of Jarvish's computer - this is one of 551 models of dv6 that HP produced, and I'm simply a volunteer on this site.

Comment: Hey Charles, this has nothing to do with the specific computer model; if you recommend looking at the output of anything in `/proc/` or `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` then you first need to read and understand https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt -- you will find _no_ boost info at all in those outputs. And also, the thread you suggest deals with an Intel CPU. The relevant thread for @Jarvish is http://askubuntu.com/a/501599/308343 as I pointed out in a comment above.