# Does Intel turbo boost work in Ubuntu?

Tags: intel, compatibility, cpufreq

I have an Intel i7 processor. It's frequency is 2.67 GHz, however it has turbo boost allowed to a frequency of 3.3 GHz. Is turbo boost posible using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes it works.  I verified it working on mine with 10.04.  I used this app ages ago.  http://code.google.com/p/i7z/

Answer (score 13):

if you are using ubuntu 11.04 or ubuntu 11.10 then it is possible

Try `powertop` and `turbostat` from the acpidump package (run `sudo modprobe msr` before `sudo turbostat`).

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can use turbo boost in Ubuntu.  Here is a link you might find usefull  :
[Is Turbo Boost Working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37618/is-turbo-boost-working)