# is intel turbo-boost option good for life-time?

Tags: kernel, intel, cpu, cpufreq

here is intel-core-i-7 with 2.8 Ghz resp. 3.5 Ghz as turbo-boost option.

with this question I refer to this link:

[Does Intel turbo boost work in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87610/does-intel-turbo-boost-work-in-ubuntu)

Is option of turbo-boost not harming the hardware regarding the life-time of the processor resp. of the hard-ware ?

I know by benchmarking of hard-disks - like defragmenting under windows - that such benchmarking can shorten the life-time of hardware up to 3 times ... ( my harddisk of the first PC in 2000 under windows - was broken by win98SE after only 2 years ).

when should I use turbo-boost resp. when should I avoid it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turbo doesn't harm your computer, can you find any evidence of this?

Turbo overclocks the cpu for a short period of time, so if you have bad cpu cooler it may have negative effect, but then a bad cpu cooler should be replaced. 
You should always use turbo unless the temperature of the CPU is too high (near it's max value).

Also hard drives have improved a lot since Windows 98 was released. Also defragmentation and performance test aren't the same, defragmentation moves around the files and performance test maxes the hard drive out.

Comment: Thought of that an option like turbo-boost is in the end a matter to the cpu like the option of benchmarking or of defragmenting ? Therefore I was putting this question. - So I thought it would be matter of life-time too, if I avoid turbo-boost or if not. Okay. With you answer my question is solved.  ;-)