# Turbo boost \ freq

Tags: cpu, acpi, cpufreq

I am trying to define my cpu freq when rendering in Maya for example, and I can't do it.
the cpu stays at 2900MHz.
When using windows, it use to jump to 4.2\4.5 in some scenarios.
I found this thread:
[Is Turbo Boost Working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37618/is-turbo-boost-working)

but still it doesn't help me to solve my issue...
[i7z status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW5jp.png)

so first of why I cant find any folder under any cpu named "cpufreq"
actually the cpufreq folder located under /sys/devices/system/cpu/
and its empty.
as well as, why does it says that my hyper threading is OFF?
can't find a way to turn it ON, is it necessary to turn it ON for better performance?

by the way, i added this acpi=off command, since the ubuntu is stuck on purple screen if i doesn't... i tried each acpi option, and none of them work except off...
Thank you so much!
I must say that I'v learned a lot of your commands here!

Comment: On your first link, did you scroll down to the fourth answer that states the accepted answer doesn't work?

Comment: hey there, yes I did read the fourth answer,
But actually I was running the exact same simulation in Houdini, on both windows and ubuntu, ofc same machine, and in Windows it was almost 2 times faster.
I am pretty sure that my computer isn't run at highest performance on Ubuntu.
thanks for your help