# Turbo Boost Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, intel, turbo-boost

Hello and good afternoon,

I'm fairly new to the Ubuntu ecosystem and i was wondering if there is a way to disable turbo boost on my machine (Bios option not available) i tried following a guide from back in 2015 using msr-tools but did not worked as intended not sure if its even possible but its making my computer fan spinning loudly while I'm just web browsing and i do not use anything intensive that requires a boots on the CPU. My question is: Is there a way to disable turbo boost completely?

Comment: As you are running `14.04` this means 2 things: **A)** Your question will likely be closed soon and **B)** You have an old laptop that might need dust cleaned off fan and internal components (like CPU) See: [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872)

Comment: 1) Please see https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-14-04-end-of-life/  2) While you are considering upgrading to 16.04, 18.04, or 19.04, please also run `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer`


and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit]. Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Comment: Sorry im not using 14.04 i'm currently using the latest one which is 18.04.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable turbo boost (for Intel anyway) use this command:

```
$ echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

---

Another option is to limit your CPU frequencies to non-turbo boost speeds or even lower. For this purpose I wrote `cpuf`:

- [GUI or simple Bash script to throttle the CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141605/gui-or-simple-bash-script-to-throttle-the-cpu/1142671#1142671)

[image: cpuf-demo.gif]

Visit the link to copy the script or get more details.

Comment: I attempted to run that command from terminal and got an error message stating command not found. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @Vilden do not enter the `$` prompt that is already displayed. Enter after the prompt: `echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

Comment: It seems that one worked how would i know if its in fact running?

Comment: type `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` and if it returns `1` then turbo is off. It it returns `0` then turbo is on.

Comment: Great it came back with 1 appreciate the help and support apologize if my thread contained misleading information. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @Vilden nothing was misleading. Please click the check mark next the solution that answers your question. This lets others know the solution to the question and gives points to the person who answered the question. Plus it gives 2 more points to yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Done i selected the check mark as well thank you.