# Performance mode disabled because of false positive reading

Tags: nvidia, graphics, power-management, temperature, 23.10

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 and for some reason, I'm seeing this message because the operating temperatures are too high:

> Performance mode temporarily disabled due to high operating temperature.

[image: performance mode being disabled]

This is kind of odd to me because it wasn't there before and I can assure you that my temperatures are *not* too high. See below the output of some relevant commands:

- Output of `uname -a`:

  ```
  Linux exbigboss-ubuntu 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:59:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- Output of `sensors`:

  ```
  coretemp-isa-0000
  Adapter: ISA adapter
  Package id 0:  +28.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 0:        +25.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 4:        +25.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 8:        +23.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 12:       +22.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 16:       +23.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 20:       +22.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 24:       +25.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 28:       +25.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 36:       +24.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 37:       +24.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 38:       +24.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)
  Core 39:       +24.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +80.0°C)

  acpitz-acpi-0
  Adapter: ACPI interface
  temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +85.0°C)

  iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
  Adapter: Virtual device
  temp1:        +35.0°C  

  nvme-pci-0700
  Adapter: PCI adapter
  Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  =  -5.2°C, high = +79.8°C)
                         (crit = +84.8°C)
  ```
- Output of `nvidia-smi`:

  ```
  Sun Dec 31 07:12:21 2023       
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
  |-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  | GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
  | Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
  |                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
  |=========================================+======================+======================|
  |   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
  |  0%   43C    P8              14W / 220W |    497MiB /  8192MiB |      8%      Default |
  |                                         |                      |                  N/A |
  +-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  ```

This seems like a false positive to me and I'm not sure exactly how to fix it. Maybe some config file somewhere got borked by a system update. I'm also noticing that even though my screen will blank, it doesn't actually turn off either and I read this is an artifact of *Performance Mode* so I thought they might be related issues.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I too saw this message on one of my PCs recently. On Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I monitor temperature via Conky desktop displays and no temperatures were high, The `Performance` radio button was still selected and I can still select between that and the other 2 options. In my case when I ran `cpufreq-info` I could see my PC was still running at full speed and changing to the other power modes I could see were changing the cpu frequency down as I would expect. So in my case I just put it down to false message and ignored it. But try the command to see what your CPU is doing.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem but, you can override the CPU frequency. Here's a GUI utility I wrote: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141605/gui-or-simple-bash-script-to-throttle-the-cpu/1142671#1142671